# Determining stride of arrays

Tags: c, compiler-construction, llvm, clang

I am trying to perform LoopDependenceAnalysis on arrays in LLVM. For this I have written a LLVM LoopPass. I am able to detect the arrays using GetElementPtr.I am unable to determine the stride of an array used in a loop.

For example, I have a c code

```
int b[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    b[i] = b[i+2];
}
```

Now in both the array accesses, the first array access (b[i] ) has a stride of 0 while the second one has a stride of 2. How is it possible to determine those values ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with LLVM, but perusing the source of `LoopDependenceAnalysis` I see `getLinearExpression` being used to determine the coefficients possibly (with an example in `analyseSIV`).

Comment: @sixlettervariables can you please share the link ? The doxygen gives 404 error and the source doesn't contain any function named getLinearExpression in LoopDependenceAnalysis.cpp

Comment: [I saw it in a code review of the class you noted](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.devel/48338).